# Whitelabel page error for graphql mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graphql

I'm new to spring boot and trying to learn how to implement graphql. @GetMapping and @PostMapping work as normal but when I try to use @QueryMapping or @SchemaMapping, following the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#overview) I get the whitelabel error page. Playing around I'm able to guess that it's not recognizing these two as mapping. I've checked my dependencies but I'll include them below in case, I've verified the project structure, and I've also tried changing from @Controller to @RestController to no avail.

Controller file

```
package com.example.GraphQLBooks.controller;

import com.example.GraphQLBooks.model.Book;
import com.example.GraphQLBooks.repository.BookRepository;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.SchemaMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class BookController {


    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookController(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    //This works with @RestController but breaks with @Controller
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String controllerTest(){
        return "Hello";
    }
    //@SchemaMapping(typeName = "Query",value = "allBooks")
    @QueryMapping
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>GraphQL-Books</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GraphQL-Books</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true
```

I tested the repositories using @GetMapping and they output as expected and when I got to my "/test" mapping it outputs Hello as expected. Any insight and tips are appreciated, and let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue. The problem was graphqls file wasn't placed in the right folder.
Spring boot graphQL looks for the graphqls file in the following directory by default: `~/src/main/resources/graphql/schema.graphqls`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My schema had a typo had schema.graphql instead of schema.graphqls and it should be localhost:8080/graphiql not localhost:8080/graphql dumb mistakes I know. And you can't use @RestController with graphql has to be @Controller which makes sense because we're not using a Rest Api.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).